# How to retrieve a value that must be computed on another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, event-dispatch-thread

There are many cases where thread A requires a value that must be computed on thread B.  (Most commonly, B == EDT.)  Consider this example:

```
String host;
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        host = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter host name: ");
    }
});
openConnection(host);
```

Of course, this doesn't compile, because the anonymous inner class isn't allowed to write to `host`.  What's the simplest, cleanest way to get this to work?  I've included the ways I know of below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No:

Use a [`Future<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) and possibly [`Callable<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) and an [`ExecutorService`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).  A **`Future`** is basically an exact programmatic expression of what you want: **a promise of a future answer, and the ability to block until the answer is available**.  Future also automatically wraps and presents for you an entire, complicated farrago of potential concurrency nightmares and complexities into a few clearly defined exceptions.  This is a **good thing** because it forces you to deal with them, when a roll-your-own solution would likely never reveal them except in some aberrant, difficult to diagnose behavior.

```
public void askForAnAnswer() throws TimeoutException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException
{
  Future<String> theAnswerF = getMeAnAnswer();
  String theAnswer = theAnswerF.get();

}

public Future<String> getMeAnAnswer()
{
  Future<String> promise = null;
  // spin off thread/executor, whatever.
  SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    host = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter host name: ");
  }
 });
 // ... to wrap a Future around this.

  return promise;
}
```

For your specific case, you can probably build on a [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) which implements `Future`.  Rather than duplicate, please take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281855/what-is-the-rationale-of-swingworker).

Comment: +1 -- this is truly the right way to handle this in Java. They added Future/Callable specifically to deal with Runnables that return things.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this to its logical conclusion, and have produced way more code than I think ought to be necessary.  One thing I'm struggling with is, if SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait() throws and InterruptedException, how do I know whether my task actually completed on the EDT?  Maybe that deserves its own question ...

Comment: s/and InterruptedException/an InterrputedException/

Comment: Ah, here's a way to get around that.  And substituting in a Callable for a Runnable in the method argument yields, I think, basically what I was looking for: http://blog.palantirtech.com/2008/02/21/invokeandnotwaiting/

Answer (score 1):

```
    final SynchronousQueue<String> host = new SynchronousQueue<String>();

    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            host.add(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter host name: "));
        }

    });

    openConnection(host.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the accepted answer on the very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397480/java-swing-application-how-to-get-data-from-the-gui-thread-to-another-thread?rq=1, and the more I think about it the more I like it.

Answer (score 0):

### Verbose: Use an inner class

```
class HostGetter implements Runnable{
    volatile String host;
    public void run() {
        host = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter host name: ");
    }
}
HostGetter hg = new HostGetter();
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(hg);
openConnection(hg.host);
```

Comment: This one at least gets you the right answer, but it doesn't let you do anything in the interim.

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend to create a class to handle this, samples below:

```
class SyncUserData implements Runnable {
    private String value ;

    public void run() {
        value = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter host name: ") ;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value ;
    }
}
// Using an instance of the class launch the popup and get the data.
String host;
SyncUserData syncData = new SyncUserData() ;
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(syncData);
host = syncData.getValue() ;
```

I'll extend this approach by making the class abstract and using generics to allow any type of values to be return.

```
abstract class SyncUserDataGeneric<Type> implements Runnable {
    private Type value ;
    public void run() {
        value = process();
    }
    public Type getValue() {
        return value ;
    }

    public abstract Type process() ;
}

String host;
SyncUserDataGeneric<String> doHostnameGen ;

doHostnameGen = new SyncUserDataGeneric<String>() {
    public String process() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter host name: ");
    }
};

host = doHostnameGen.getValue() ;
```

EDIT: Checks if running from the EventDispatchThread.

```
if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
    host = doHostnameGen.process() ;
} else {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(doHostnameGen) ;
    host = doHostnameGen.getValue() ;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't SyncUserData[Generic].value need to be volatile to guarantee visibility?

Comment: No in this case, invokeAndWait guarantees the main thread will wait for the SyncUserDataGeneric to return, no locking needed. Edit for case where the code is running from an EventDispatcherThread (fired by an ActionLister).

Answer (score 0):

**Please note: the author doesn't like this answer, it's just the "on the nose" answer to the specific question.**

If you're only looking for a wait to minimally modify the above code so it works, you're dealing with the inner-class-can-only-refer-to-finals problem.  Carve out a named inner class instead of an anonymous one and create a String host field in that class.  Pass that instance to `invokeAndWait()`.  But this is still icky, in my humble opinion, and far inferior to the `Future<>` approach I cited above.

```
class FooWidget implements Runnable() {
  AtomicReference<String> host = new AtomicReference<String>(null);
  @Override
  public void run() {
    host.set(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter host name: "));
  }
}

...

FooWidget foo = new FooWidget();
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(foo);
if (foo.host.get() == null) { throw new SomethingWentWrongException(); }
openConnection(foo.host.get());
```

Comment: Doesn't FooWidget.host need to be volatile to guarantee visibility?

Comment: Yes, or any of a number of other solutions... For this and other reasons, please see my other answer for a cleaner, more robust approach.  See my update, I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

### Elegant? Use an atomic variable

```
final AtomicReference<String> host = new AtomicReference<String>();
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        host.set(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter host name: "));
    }
});
openConnection(host.get());
```

Comment: This one is only incorrect due to synchronization issues (how do you know host[0] will be set by the time it's referenced? (answer, it probably won't be, with the user drooling away at the console...)

Comment: @andersoj: I know it will be set because I'm using invokeAndWait() rather than invokeLater().  (I assume you mean host.get() rather than host[0].)

Comment: You know that assuming everything goes to plan.  If the thread gets lost, encounters an exception, etc... who knows?

Answer (score -1):

### Hack: Use an array

```
final String[] host = new String[1];
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        host[0] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter host name: ");
    }
});
openConnection(host[0]); //maybe not guaranteed to be visible by the memory model?
```

Comment: incorrect due to visibility *and* synchronization issues (how do you know host[0] will be set by the time it's referenced?  (answer, it probably won't be, with the user drooling away at the console...)