# Java - Cannot assign a value to final variable query. It is final String

Tags: java, jbutton

I have a problem with final string. It is a mysql database client.
I want to change query with clicking JButton.

```
public void run() {
final String query;
(...)
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
if(firstSel==null || selchose.getText().equals(selchose_str) || selbase.getText().equals(base_str)) {
            query = "Select * FROM EMP";
        }
(...)
```

The problem is with

```
query = "Select * FROM EMP";
```

It shows me

cannot assign a value to final variable query

How to solve the problem?

Comment: I asked [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981924/how-to-retrieve-a-value-that-must-be-computed-on-another-thread) a while back that gets at this same issue, and may be informative to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class YOurClassName{

private String query; //make here.....<<<<<<<<

public void run() {

(...)
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
if(firstSel==null || selchose.getText().equals(selchose_str) || selbase.getText().equals(base_str)) {
            query = "Select * FROM EMP";
        }
(...)


}
```

Comment: @Ganjira: you really couldn't figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Either make the query String a private class field or a variable local to the anonymous inner ActionListener class.

Comment: @Ganjira: ??? This is trivial. Just declare query as a variable of the class not a variable inside just the run method. Surely you know how to do this, right?

Comment: Well, i declared query outside of the run method, but it shows the same problem. :/

Comment: Not outside the run method, but in the class, up at the top. It will fix it.