# What can I use in core Java as an alternative of Async Task in Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, playn

I have created an app in android. Now I want to create a web version using PlayN. What I want is to replace all the android specific code to normal java code.  In android version I use Async task. What can I use instead of this?

Comment: this can help : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: Wow, that's quite a mission. I hope you do well with that. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Here is a AsynTask file which you might use it as a Java code https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java

Comment: nibha,  I am using PlayN. will swing be a good option then?

Comment: Vinayak, You mean I have to pull the class from there and use it in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async Task is nothing but just a separate thread.You can create your on thread and add the code which you written in doInBackground(Void... params)  in the thread's run() method.

Comment: Dhavai  what about onPreExecute   and  onPostExecute ? And I need to update UI too.

Comment: This thing is done by your main thread which call childthread.start() method.

Comment: and see the Thread.Join() function. By this function u can block your main thread till the childthread is complete its work. And after join() write your onPostExecute () code.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Other refefernces:

1. [How do I use SwingWorker in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782265/how-do-i-use-swingworker-in-java)
2. [Java GUI threads - SwingWorker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159547/java-gui-threads-swingworker)
3. [What is the rationale of SwingWorker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281855/what-is-the-rationale-of-swingworker)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Android Source and copy the AsyncTask source to your project. Its does not have dependency of Android.

You can find AsyncTask.java [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/os/AsyncTask.java)

Comment: Link is broken...http 502